# Simple SQL Query Error

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I've been trying to debug this [query that I'm using to practice on](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ovUAj5FSCuWaFatZEnpfzd/2).

The error I'm getting when trying to build is:

> Schema Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '); INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerId, CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City)' at line 10

I've tried multiple fixes, I've removed any unnecessary fluff, but I'm not sure why I still can't get it working.

---

**Update**
I've updated [the link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ovUAj5FSCuWaFatZEnpfzd/3) to show trying to add a Foreign Key.

Comment: The error message always points exactly at, or immediately after, the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra comma at the end of your `Customers` create table definition. Specifically, line 9's primary key has an extra comma at the end.

Same thing for your `Orders` table definition, the primary key definition for `OrderId` has an extra comma too.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
  CustomerId int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  CustomerName varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  ContactName varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  Address varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  City varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CustomerId), <---------- here
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Orders (
  OrderId int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  CustomerId int(6) NOT NULL,
  OrderDate varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  Product varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderId`), <--- and here
);
```

Comment: Would you mind looking at the updated link in the question. I added a single line, the Foreign Key line, and I can't get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You have error on this line

```
  PRIMARY KEY (CustomerId),
```

You have extra comma. Remove that.

Comment: Would you mind looking at the [updated link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ovUAj5FSCuWaFatZEnpfzd/4). I added a foreign key and can't get it working.

Comment: include the column name in the parenthesis, FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerId) and the datatype declaration should be the same as in the reference table, CustomerId int(6) unsigned NOT NULL

Comment: Does [this link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ovUAj5FSCuWaFatZEnpfzd/6) represent what you're talking about? I believe I typed what you said and I'm still getting an error.

Comment: use this and see the difference from your code -- CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Orders (
  OrderId int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  CustomerId int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  OrderDate varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  Product varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (OrderId),
  FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerId)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Here's an [updated schema](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ovUAj5FSCuWaFatZEnpfzd/7). Would you mind updating the code on the page, and click update and pasting the link? I tried what you said but I am still getting errors.